# How can I create a separate UserControl instance for each TabItem in a TabControl, using XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls

I'm creating a WPF Application where you can create a soundtrack.
Each soundtrack has Albums, which contain Tracks, etc etc.

I've separated the Album creation interface into its own UserControl, and then created the TabControl in the main window (henceforth referred to as The Editor)

In the main Project class, there is an ObservableCollection of Albums, and Albums have an ObservableCollection of Tracks, along with other properties.

My plan of action is to bind the TabControl to the Album ObservableCollection, so that when a new album is made, it also makes a new Tab for it. This part works so far. I can see a new tab when a new album is made, I don't have to explicitly create a new TabItem and add it myself to the TabControl.

This is the TabControl:

```
                    <TabControl x:Name="AlbumTabs" SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged" TabStripPlacement="Left" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentProject.AlbumCollection}">
                        <TabControl.Resources>
                            <DataTemplate x:Key="Album_UserControl" x:Shared="False">
                                <local:Soundtrack_Album/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </TabControl.Resources>
                        <TabControl.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="Add Album" Click="contextAddAlbum_Click" />
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </TabControl.ContextMenu>
                        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                                <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="270"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="Album"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <local:Soundtrack_Album/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    </TabControl>
```

When I create the tabs however, they all seem to be using the same instance of the UserControl. I select one tab, change some fields, select a different tab, and the fields are still the same. Shouldn't the content change when I select a different tab?

I'm also noticing that the Items of the TabControl are actually Albums, and not TabItems. I'm guessing this isn't correct, as my next problem will be trying to set the DataContext of the newly-created TabItem to the newly-created Album.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, the all should use same instance of control only DataContext will be changed on controls. About, content not being changed, you might have problem with binding/control. Can you post taht code as well?

Comment: Also, Items should be coming from your ItemSource so albums being TabControl Items is expected behavior.